# Storyboard: How to set a UIToolbar at the bottom of a UITableViewController controlled by a UINavigationViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uitoolbar

I'm new to the Cocoa topic. I build with  the Storyboard a small application which runs just fine. 
I'm pushing `UITableViewController` to another one, controlled by the `UINavigationViewController`. Now I need a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem` fixed at the bottom of the screen.
Here can you see my Storyboard [image] So I added via drag and drop a Toolbar and in the toolbar an button into the `Period TableViewController`, thus it is on the same hierarchic level like the `UITableView`.
Unfortunately neither the "**PayOff**" Button nor a bottom Toolbar does appear in the app.

Can you help me, what is wrong with my Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewController try adding this

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

and use this to add BarItems to it

```
[self setToolbarItems:@[item1, item2, item3] animated:YES];
```

I'm using this method to add a scan button to a UITableViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *rightSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
...
...
UIBarButtonItem *scanItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:scanButton];

[self setToolbarItems:@[leftSpace, scanItem, rightSpace] animated:YES];
```

You should be careful because the ToolBar visibility is set for the entire NavigationController you are using and you should show/hide it when needed.

Also the items on it need to be set on each controller (I have this issue, maybe there is a better way to do it)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx alot, solved it. Concerning the UIBarButtonItem I referenced an IBOutlet into the PeriodTableViewController.h and added it to the ToolbarItems. Works fine!